# Stored Procedure Where Parameter SqlDbType

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a combobox and a textbox.
I use the combobox value for @criteria and texbox value for @value
but when I execute this there is no data showed up.
I already analyzing the problem is within :

```
    select * from Table where @criteria like '%'+@value+'%'
```

from what I tested, the data showed up if my value is a part of @criteria string. So if the @criteria is 'Name' so the data only showed up if @value is 'n' or 'a' or 'm' or 'e'

How can I make it works?

```
OpenConn()
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Cmd.CommandText = "Find"
    Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Criteria", SqlDbType.varchar).Value = CmbCriteria.Text
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtValue.Text
    Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Do While Dr.Read
        Dim lv As ListViewItem
        lv = ListView1.Items.Add(Dr("No"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(Dr("Name"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(Dr("Address"))
    Loop
CloseConn()
```

Comment: Use `CmbCriteria.SelectedItem.Text` or `CmbCriteria.SelectedItem.Value` based on what you need. Also is that `SqlDbType.varchar` a typo? Cause you have `SqlDbType.Varchar` for the Value parameter and not for the Criteria.

Comment: @Nilesh I change the code a little there, don't know why it's looked like a typo but I assure you that isn't the case. regarding the  'cmbkriteria.selecteditem.text' or 'cmbcriteria.selecteditem.value' it returns 'Public member 'text'/'value' on type 'String' not found.'

Comment: Make sure that  you have `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you are expecting that "@criteria" will be your database field name.  Parameters in ADO.NET (and in nearly all modern methods of database access) refer to data values and can never be used as database field names.

Comment: this is right although it doesn't help with my problem. the fact states that my code is wrong. I'll find a way around.

Comment: Be careful to avoid sql injection attacks.  You might try a case statement listing all possible search fields like the following: select * from Table where
case when @criteria = 'FIELDNAME' then FIELDNAME like '%'+@value+'%' end but hopefully you find something smoother.